# Convert specific lines into lists using Python

Tags: python

I am trying to take 200 lines and convert each group of 10 into its own list.

```
1
Victorious Boom
834
7
0
7.00
1
0
1.00
1
2
Tier 1 Smurf
806
4
0
4.00
1
0
1.00
1
3
AllHailHypnoToad
754
4
0
4.00
1
0
1.00
1
```

which I want to look like:

```
1 Victorious Boom 834 7 0 7.00 1 0 1.00 1
2 Tier 1 Smurf 806 4 0 4.00 1 0 1.00 1
3 AllHailHypnoToad 754 4 0 4.00 1 0 1.00 1
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

Comment: Please show us what you have attempted so far, and demonstrate how the output does not give what you require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
full_list = [line.strip() for line in open("filename", 'r')] #read all lines into list
sublist = [full_list[i:i+10] for i in range(0, len(full_list), 10)]  #split them into sublist with 10 lines each
```

Comment: I was able to make this semi-work. I used an earlier list of that data, but it contains HTML table data from earlier in the scrape. What's the best way to remove the <td> and </td> from the list?
`[[<td>1</td>, <td>Victorious Boom</td>, <td>834</td>, <td>7</td>, <td>0</td>, <td>7.00</td>, <td>1</td>, <td>0</td>, <td>1.00</td>, <td>1</td>], [<td>2</td>, <td>Tier 1 Smurf</td>, <td>806</td>, <td>4</td>, <td>0</td>, <td>4.00</td>, <td>1</td>, <td>0</td>, <td>1.00</td>, <td>1</td>]]`

Comment: I found a way around it by including  
`import re`  
`regex = '<td>(.+?)</td>'` 
`pattern = re.compile(regex)`  
  
then in my while loop adding:  
`table = re.findall(pattern, "list obj here")`
`subtable = subtable = [table[i:i+10] for i in range(0, len(table), 10)]`   
  
Responds with:  
`[['1', 'Victorious Boom', '834', '7', '0', '7.00', '1', '0', '1.00', '1'], ['2', 'Tier 1 Smurf', '806', '4', '0', '4.00', '1', '0', '1.00', '1']`

Answer (score 0):

```
count=0
fixed_list=[]
temp_list=[]
for line in open("some.txt").readlines():
    count+=1
    temp_list.append(line.strip())
    if (count%10)==0:
        fixed_list.append(temp_list)
        temp_list=[]
print fixed_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer.
It takes a source.txt with the line by line type data and outputs the data in sets of 10 into the target.txt file. I hope this helps.

```
file  = open("source.txt", "r")
data = []
for line in file:
    data.append(line)
length = len(data)
file.close()

#output file
target = open("target.txt", "w")

#will become a line in the file
item = ""

if length % 10 == 0:
    for y in range(0, length, 10): 
        for x in range(0, 10):
            item += str(data[x + y].strip()) + " "
        target.write(item + "\n")
        item = ""   
else:
    print ("Bad data set. File "+ str(length) + " elements!")
```